# Suggestion to handle requests.exceptions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to the requests module and I'm trying to scrape data from an auction website. This requires me to send a lot of requests.get(...). Most of the time, it works fine but because of network issues, sometimes it fails and makes my entire program crash.

The error is:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I'm using a for loop for retries and this makes my program more robust but it still breaks at some point.

Here's my code:

```
def connect(link)
   for i in range(5):
      try: 
         return requests.get(link, proxies = {'http': None}).text
      except Exception as connecting_error:
         time.sleep(5)
         continue

page = connect(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Because `connect()` returns `None`, meaning it has gone out of the loop, it raises a `TypeError` when I try to create the soup object? Should I put this into a While loop instead? Any suggestion please?

Comment: Define what you mean by `it still breaks at some point.` what breaks? how does it break

Comment: The crash you are describing is probably not in the shown part of the code as you actually handle all `Exceptions`  (almost all, ...)

Comment: I create a BeautifulSoup object based on the request. And because this returns nothing, meaning it has gone out of the loop, it raises a TypeError.

Comment: You are doing that afterwards though .. not in the code shown in your post

Comment: The Python code still doesn't show anything related to bs and therefore not the code which raises your `TypeError`.